# Select values from related entities by related entity id

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to select child element (many to one) modsVersionses of parent element Mods with Hibernate 5. In the same time, modsVersionses should be filtered by modsVersionses.id.

I've tried something like this:

```
    Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = s.getEntityManagerFactory().getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Mods> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Mods.class);
    Root<Mods> root = criteriaQuery.from(Mods.class);

    criteriaQuery.select(root.get("modsVersionses"));
    criteriaQuery
            .where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), id)).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("modsVersionses").get("id"), versionId));

    List<Mods> resultList = s.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();

    Mods mod = resultList.get(0);
```

But I got IllegalStateException on code `.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("modsVersionses").get("id"), versionId))` .

How to correctly filter child elements by id?

Thank you!

**Update 1**: With @JB Nizet help I made changes and my code now is:

Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = s.getEntityManagerFactory().getCriteriaBuilder();

```
    CriteriaQuery<Mod> cq = cb.createQuery(Mod.class);

    SetJoin<Mod, ModVersion> modsVersionsesNode = cq.from(Mod.class).join(Mod_.modsVersionses);

    cq.where(
            cb.equal(
                    modsVersionsesNode.get(ModVersion_.id), versionId
            )
    );

    List<Mod> mods = s.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

But I still can't understand, how to select not Mod object, but to select only ModVersion?

Comment: Why don't you use the metamodel classes, which would make your queries safe? Or even better, use JPQL, which would make your code readable? `select mods from Mods mods join mods.modsVersionses v where mods.id = :id and c.id = :versionId`? Using the singular form for your classes (Mod), and actual english words (modVersions) would also help.

Comment: I thought about HQL or JPQL, but this is not production code, only for learning purposes - I want to understand, how to realize it with Criteria.

Comment: Then learn how to generate the metamodel classes and use them in your query, because that's the right way to do it. When you've done it and updated your code, if it's still doesn't work, post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception. **Always** do that when asking about an exception.

Comment: Are you talking about https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about.

Comment: Updated my post, can you check it? But I still can't understand, how to select not Mod object, but to select only ModVersion?

Comment: Use a CriteriaQuery<ModVersion>. And add a select: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#select-javax.persistence.criteria.Selection-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, thanks to @JB Nizet :

```
    Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = s.getEntityManagerFactory().getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<ModVersion> cq = cb.createQuery(ModVersion.class);
    Root<Mod> root = cq.from(Mod.class);
    SetJoin<Mod, ModVersion> join = root.join(Mod_.modsVersionses);

    cq.select(
            join
    );

    cq.where(
            cb.equal(
                    join.get(ModVersion_.id), versionId
            )
    );

    List<ModVersion> mods = s.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```